# Assign to child model items from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model

I'm trying to assign values to items within a child model but don't seem to be able to do this.

```
     var model = new WOLFormViewModel
        {
            LastS= 0,                                    
            Start = sitecustomattributes.Start,
            End = sitecustomattributes.End,
            PrimeSel = false,
            ADFSel = false,
            SupplementarySel = false,
            BondSel = false,
            SheetNo = 0,
            EntryOneModel.Code = 1234                                         

        };
```

EntryOneModel is a public class within WOLFormViewModel.

Does anyone know why I can't assign data to EntryOneModel.Code = 1234?

Comment: `EntryOneModel = new yourClassName { Code = 1234 }`

Comment: Thanks, EntryOneModel is the class name: '  public class WOLFormViewModel
    {


        public EntryOneModel EntryOne { get; set; }
      
    }

    public class EntryOneModel
    {

        public long WOLId { get; set; }
'

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = new WOLFormViewModel
{
    LastS= 0,                                    
    Start = sitecustomattributes.Start,
    End = sitecustomattributes.End,
    PrimeSel = false,
    ADFSel = false,
    SupplementarySel = false,
    BondSel = false,
    SheetNo = 0,
    EntryOne = new EntryOneModel() { Code = 1234 )                                         
};
```